# Disable automatic resizing, without disabling manual resizing

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-2

Coding a GUI in a Java project I've encountered a problem with JavaFX.
I've not found any soulutions for my specific problem, so here I am:)

Is it possible to let a JavaFX scene be resizeable by the user and at the same time have it not resized by child nodes, that are bigger, than the window?

Here is some sample code:

```
@Override
public void startGUI(int width, int height) {
    this.main = new MainWindow(this, this.logic);
    this.scene = new Scene(this.main.getRoot());
    this.main.setScene(this.scene);
    this.primaryStage.setScene(this.scene);
    this.primaryStage.setMinHeight(height);
    this.primaryStage.setMinWidth(width);
}
```

The 'MainWindow' has got a childnode, that can be very big (>1024x768). 
I want the window not to be resized by this node, but at the same time, the user should be able to resize the window by dragging its borders.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted some sample code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: I'm sorry, thought the description was clear enough. Added some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Scene constructor which specifies initial size constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#Scene%28javafx.scene.Parent,%20double,%20double%29).

For example:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
```

That way the initial size of the Scene will be taken from these constraints rather than calculated from the preferred size of the root node.